# Python - manipulate odds

Tags: python, random

**Introduction:**

I am trying to make a simple for in a row game using python. For one of my modules I need the computer to randomly choose a character to insert in the playing grid. I would like to have more control over the odds of what character is chosen.

**Python Version:**

3.4

**Scenario 1:**

Call `random.choice("XO ")`

**Scenario 2:**

A quick hack to manipulate the odds

Call `random.choice("XXOO ")`

**What I want:**

A solution that increases the chances of an `"O"` or `"X"` being chosed, decrease the chance of an `" "` (whitespace) being chosen

**What I don't want:**

Adding in more characters of the `"O"`s and `"X"`s to increase the odds. E.g. `"XXOO "` would give me 2:1 odds for the "X"s and `"O"`s
This seems like a bad hack

Comment: Are you trying to make this code so that someone looking at it won't be able to tell you have twisted the odds?

Comment: @DavidGreydanus no, this is just for a testing module of the game.

Comment: I would use random.random

Comment: Here's a naive/simple approach: https://gist.github.com/tristanfisher/9fa381d28e2e023cfbc5